# Kivy dynamically adding buttons to gridlayout gives error

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to populate a Gridlayout inside of a ScrollView dynamically. However, when I try to add the buttons generated by Builder.load_string, I get the following error:
kivy.uix.widget.WidgetException: Cannot add , it already has a parent 
I am unsure of what I am doing wrong.
I could generate each button in python by constructor, but I would rather not rewrite the button generation.

main.py

```py
# IMSA Computational Science and Data Science Club: Brummet Client
# Written for ssh into IMSA SLURM cluster
# Written by: Arthur Lu, Jacob Levine
# Use at one's own risk

__author__ = ("Arthur Lu <alu1@imsa.edu>", "Jacob Levine <jlevine@imsa.edu>")

from kivy.config import Config
#Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)

from kivy.app import App

from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty

from kivy.core.window import Window

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition, NoTransition
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label

from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

from kivy.clock import Clock

import csv
import paramiko
import time
#import os

def load_csv(filepath):
    with open(filepath, newline='') as csvfile:
        file_array = list(csv.reader(csvfile))
        csvfile.close() 
    return file_array

class Client(Screen):

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        Window.size = (1280, 720)
        Window.top = 100
        Window.left = 100

    def client(self, ssh, sftp):

        self.ssh = ssh
        self.sftp = sftp

        self.sftp.chdir('brummet_projects')

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.auto, 1)

    def auto(self, dt):

        projects = self.sftp.listdir('.')

        for file in projects:

            if file[0] == ".":

                projects.remove(file)

        list_view = self.ids.list_files

        """
        Button:
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            Image:
                source:'data\customui\client_file_bar.png'
                x: self.parent.x
                y: self.parent.y
                width: self.parent.width
                height: self.parent.height
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: False

            Image:
                source:'data\customui\python.png'
                y: self.parent.y + 10
                x: - self.parent.width/2 + 25
                width: self.parent.width - 20
                height: self.parent.height - 20

            Label:
                size_hint:(0.9, 1)
                text: "hello there"
                y: self.parent.y
                x: self.parent.x + self.parent.width*0.05
                width: self.parent.width
                height: self.parent.height
                text_size: self.size
                font_size: self.height - 30
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'middle'

            Label:
                size_hint:(0.9, 1)
                text: "no u"
                y: self.parent.y
                x: self.parent.x + self.parent.width*0.7
                width: self.parent.width
                height: self.parent.height
                text_size: self.size
                font_size: self.height - 30
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'middle'

            Label:
                size_hint:(0.9, 1)
                text: "dong big dumb"
                y: self.parent.y
                x: self.parent.x + self.parent.width*0.8
                width: self.parent.width
                height: self.parent.height
                text_size: self.size
                font_size: self.height - 30
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'middle'
        """

        template = Builder.load_string("""
Button:
    background_color: 0,0,0,0
    Image:
        source:'data\customui\client_file_bar.png'
        x: self.parent.x
        y: self.parent.y
        width: self.parent.width
        height: self.parent.height
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False

    Image:
        source:'data\customui\python.png'
        y: self.parent.y + 10
        x: - self.parent.width/2 + 25
        width: self.parent.width - 20
        height: self.parent.height - 20

    Label:
        size_hint:(0.9, 1)
        text: "hello there"
        y: self.parent.y
        x: self.parent.x + self.parent.width*0.05
        width: self.parent.width
        height: self.parent.height
        text_size: self.size
        font_size: self.height - 30
        halign: 'left'
        valign: 'middle'

    Label:
        size_hint:(0.9, 1)
        text: "no u"
        y: self.parent.y
        x: self.parent.x + self.parent.width*0.7
        width: self.parent.width
        height: self.parent.height
        text_size: self.size
        font_size: self.height - 30
        halign: 'left'
        valign: 'middle'

    Label:
        size_hint:(0.9, 1)
        text: "dong big dumb"
        y: self.parent.y
        x: self.parent.x + self.parent.width*0.8
        width: self.parent.width
        height: self.parent.height
        text_size: self.size
        font_size: self.height - 30
        halign: 'left'
        valign: 'middle'
            """)

        print(projects)

        for file in projects:
            list_view.add_widget(template)

class Connect(Screen):
    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        Window.size = (600, 300)

    def routine(self, host, port, username, password):

        ssh = None
        sftp = None

        #print(username, password)
        self.ids.status.text = "connecting"

        try:
            self.ids.status.text = "attempting to connect to " + host + ":" + str(port)
            ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            ssh.connect(host, port, username, password)

            transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
            transport.connect(username = username, password = password)
            sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

            self.ids.status.text = "connected to " + host + ":" + str(port)

            Clock.schedule_once(self.continue_to_client, 0.1)
            self.manager.get_screen('client').client(ssh, sftp)


        except Exception as e:
            if sftp is not None:
                sftp.close()
            if ssh is not None:
                ssh.close()

            self.ids.status.text = "connection failed: " + str(e)
            Clock.schedule_once(self.return_to_login, 4)
            #self.manager.current = 'login'

    def return_to_login(self, *args):
        self.manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction = "right")
        self.manager.current = 'login'
            #time.sleep(5)

    def continue_to_client(self, *args):

        self.manager.transition = NoTransition()
        self.manager.current = 'client'

class Login(Screen):

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        Window.size = (600, 300)

    def do_login(self, loginText, passwordText, hostText, portText):
        app = App.get_running_app()

        if hostText == "":
            hostText = "titanrobotics.ddns.net"
        if portText == "":
            portText = "60022"

        host = hostText
        port = int(portText)

        username = loginText
        password = passwordText

        self.manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction = "left")
        self.manager.current = "connect"

        self.manager.get_screen('connect').routine(host, port, username, password)

    def resetForm(self):
        self.ids['login'].text = ""
        self.ids['password'].text = ""


manager = ScreenManager()

class BrummetApp(App):

    username = StringProperty(None)
    password = StringProperty(None)

    title = 'Brummet Client v ' + load_csv("data/meta")[0][1]

    def check_resize(self, instance, x, y):
        # resize X
        #screenName = manager.current
        #print(screenName)
        if manager.current != "client":

            target_x = 600
            target_y = 300


            if x >  target_x:
                Window.size = (target_x, Window.size[1])

            if y > target_y:
                Window.size = (Window.size[0], target_y)

            if x <  target_x:
                Window.size = (target_x, Window.size[1])

            if y < target_y:
                Window.size = (Window.size[0], target_y)

        if manager.current == "client":

            target_x = 1280
            target_y = 720

            if x <  target_x:
                Window.size = (target_x, Window.size[1])

            if y < target_y:
                Window.size = (Window.size[0], target_y)

    def build(self):

        manager.add_widget(Login(name = 'login'))
        manager.add_widget(Connect(name = 'connect'))
        manager.add_widget(Client(name = 'client'))

        Window.bind(on_resize=self.check_resize)

        return manager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BrummetApp().run()
```

brummet.kv

```
<Login>:
    BoxLayout:
        id: login_layout
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: [10,10,10,10]
        spacing: 10

        BoxLayout:
            spacing: 10
            orientation:'vertical'

            Label:
                id: title
                text: 'Brummet Client'
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'middle'
                font_size: 24

            Label:
                text: 'Please log in with IMSA SLURM credentials'
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'middle'
                font_size: 20

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Label:
                size_hint: (0.15, 1)
                text: 'Username'
                font_size: 18
                halign: 'left'

            TextInput:
                size_hint: (0.7, 1)
                id: username
                multiline: False
                font_size: 18
                write_tab: False

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Label:
                size_hint: (0.15, 1)
                text: 'Password'
                halign: 'left'
                font_size: 18

            TextInput:
                size_hint: (0.7, 1)
                id: password
                multiline: False
                password: True
                font_size: 18
                write_tab: False

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Label:
                size_hint: (0.15, 1)
                text: 'Host'
                halign: 'left'
                font_size: 18

            TextInput:
                size_hint: (0.7, 1)
                hint_text: 'slurm.imsa.edu'
                id: host
                multiline: False
                font_size: 18
                write_tab: False

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Label:
                size_hint: (0.15, 1)
                text: 'Port'
                halign: 'left'
                font_size: 18

            TextInput:
                size_hint: (0.7, 1)
                input_type: 'number'
                input_filter: 'int'
                hint_text: '22'
                id: port
                multiline: False
                font_size: 18
                write_tab: False

        Button:
            text: 'Log In'
            font_size: 24
            id: submit
            on_press:
                root.do_login(username.text, password.text, host.text, port.text)

<Connect>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: [0,100,0,100]
        spacing: 0

        Label:
            text:'Logging In'
            font_size: 24
            halign: 'center'
            valign: 'middle'

        Label:
            id: status
            test:''
            font_size: 12
            halign: 'center'
            valign: 'middle'
            text_size: self.size
            size_hint: 1,1
            shorten: True

<Client>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        padding: [5, 5, 5, 5]
        spacing: 5
        GridLayout:
            size_hint: (0.2, 1)
            row_default_height: self.height / 10
            row_force_default: True
            cols: 1
            Button:
            Button:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Button:
                x: 0
                y: 0
                size: (self.parent.width, 50)
                size_hint:(None, None)
                background_color: 0,0,0,0

                Label:
                    size_hint:(0.9, 1)
                    text: "My Projects"
                    y: self.parent.y
                    x: self.parent.x + self.parent.width*0
                    width: self.parent.width
                    height: self.parent.height
                    text_size: self.size
                    font_size: self.height - 10
                    halign: 'left'
                    valign: 'middle'

            Button:
                x: 0
                y: 0
                size: (self.parent.width, 50)
                size_hint:(None, None)
                background_color: 0,0,0,0

                Label:
                    size_hint:(0.9, 1)
                    text: "Project Name"
                    y: self.parent.y
                    x: self.parent.x + self.parent.width*0
                    width: self.parent.width
                    height: self.parent.height
                    text_size: self.size
                    font_size: self.height - 30
                    halign: 'left'
                    valign: 'middle'

                Label:
                    size_hint:(0.9, 1)
                    text: "Type"
                    y: self.parent.y
                    x: self.parent.x + self.parent.width*0.7
                    width: self.parent.width
                    height: self.parent.height
                    text_size: self.size
                    font_size: self.height - 30
                    halign: 'left'
                    valign: 'middle'

                Label:
                    size_hint:(0.9, 1)
                    text: "Date Modified"
                    y: self.parent.y
                    x: self.parent.x + self.parent.width*0.8
                    width: self.parent.width
                    height: self.parent.height
                    text_size: self.size
                    font_size: self.height - 30
                    halign: 'left'
                    valign: 'middle'

            ScrollView:
                GridLayout:
                    id:list_files
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    row_default_height:50
                    cols:1

                    Button:
                        background_color: 0,0,0,0
                        Image:
                            source:'data\customui\client_file_bar.png'
                            x: self.parent.x
                            y: self.parent.y
                            width: self.parent.width
                            height: self.parent.height
                            allow_stretch: True
                            keep_ratio: False

                        Image:
                            source:'data\customui\python.png'
                            y: self.parent.y + 10
                            x: - self.parent.width/2 + 25
                            width: self.parent.width - 20
                            height: self.parent.height - 20

                        Label:
                            size_hint:(0.9, 1)
                            text: "hello there"
                            y: self.parent.y
                            x: self.parent.x + self.parent.width*0.05
                            width: self.parent.width
                            height: self.parent.height
                            text_size: self.size
                            font_size: self.height - 30
                            halign: 'left'
                            valign: 'middle'

                        Label:
                            size_hint:(0.9, 1)
                            text: "no u"
                            y: self.parent.y
                            x: self.parent.x + self.parent.width*0.7
                            width: self.parent.width
                            height: self.parent.height
                            text_size: self.size
                            font_size: self.height - 30
                            halign: 'left'
                            valign: 'middle'

                        Label:
                            size_hint:(0.9, 1)
                            text: "dong big dumb"
                            y: self.parent.y
                            x: self.parent.x + self.parent.width*0.8
                            width: self.parent.width
                            height: self.parent.height
                            text_size: self.size
                            font_size: self.height - 30
                            halign: 'left'
                            valign: 'middle'
```

The error occurs with the following code:

```
template = Builder.load_string("""
Button:
    background_color: 0,0,0,0
    Image:
        source:'data\customui\client_file_bar.png'
        x: self.parent.x
        y: self.parent.y
        width: self.parent.width
        height: self.parent.height
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False

    Image:
        source:'data\customui\python.png'
        y: self.parent.y + 10
        x: - self.parent.width/2 + 25
        width: self.parent.width - 20
        height: self.parent.height - 20

    Label:
        size_hint:(0.9, 1)
        text: "hello there"
        y: self.parent.y
        x: self.parent.x + self.parent.width*0.05
        width: self.parent.width
        height: self.parent.height
        text_size: self.size
        font_size: self.height - 30
        halign: 'left'
        valign: 'middle'

    Label:
        size_hint:(0.9, 1)
        text: "no u"
        y: self.parent.y
        x: self.parent.x + self.parent.width*0.7
        width: self.parent.width
        height: self.parent.height
        text_size: self.size
        font_size: self.height - 30
        halign: 'left'
        valign: 'middle'

    Label:
        size_hint:(0.9, 1)
        text: "dong big dumb"
        y: self.parent.y
        x: self.parent.x + self.parent.width*0.8
        width: self.parent.width
        height: self.parent.height
        text_size: self.size
        font_size: self.height - 30
        halign: 'left'
        valign: 'middle'
            """)

        print(projects)

        for file in projects:
            list_view.add_widget(template)
```

The code above should generate a few buttons in the ScrollView, however the following error is produced:
kivy.uix.widget.WidgetException: Cannot add , it already has a parent

Comment: Please post a *minimal* runnable example, something with as little code as possible to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: there are too many dependent things, but the pertaining code is where the Builder.load_string is. Under the Client class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Root cause - adding same instance, *template*

In the `for loop`, the first `add_widget()` of instance, `template` worked fine. But the second `add_widget()` of the same instance of `template` on-wards is throwing out the error. Because `template` already has a parent.

## Solution - adding new instance, *template*

There are two solutions to the problem.

### Method 1 - Create a new kv file, *template.kv*

Create a new kv file, template.kv and add a new instance of this object in the `for` loop.

#### template.kv

```
Button:
    background_color: 0,0,0,0
    Image:
        source: 'data\customui\client_file_bar.png'
        x: self.parent.x
        y: self.parent.y
        width: self.parent.width
        height: self.parent.height
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False

    Image:
        source: 'data\customui\python.png'
        y: self.parent.y + 10
        x: - self.parent.width/2 + 25
        width: self.parent.width - 20
        height: self.parent.height - 20

    Label:
        size_hint:(0.9, 1)
        text: "hello there"
        y: self.parent.y
        x: self.parent.x + self.parent.width*0.05
        width: self.parent.width
        height: self.parent.height
        text_size: self.size
        font_size: self.height - 30
        halign: 'left'
        valign: 'middle'

    Label:
        size_hint:(0.9, 1)
        text: "no u"
        y: self.parent.y
        x: self.parent.x + self.parent.width*0.7
        width: self.parent.width
        height: self.parent.height
        text_size: self.size
        font_size: self.height - 30
        halign: 'left'
        valign: 'middle'

    Label:
        size_hint:(0.9, 1)
        text: "dong big dumb"
        y: self.parent.y
        x: self.parent.x + self.parent.width*0.8
        width: self.parent.width
        height: self.parent.height
        text_size: self.size
        font_size: self.height - 30
        halign: 'left'
        valign: 'middle'
```

#### main.py

```
class Client(Screen):
    ...
    def auto(self, dt):

        projects = self.sftp.listdir('.')

        for file in projects:

            if file[0] == ".":
                projects.remove(file)

        list_view = self.ids.list_files

        print(projects)

        for file in projects:
            list_view.add_widget(Builder.load_file('template.kv'))
```

### Method 2 - Adding new class

Create a *class rule* in kv file, and add a new instance of this object in the `for` loop.

### Snippets - kv file

```
<FileTemplate>:
    background_color: 0,0,0,0
    Image:
        source: 'data\customui\client_file_bar.png'
        x: self.parent.x
        y: self.parent.y
        width: self.parent.width
        height: self.parent.height
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False

    Image:
        source: 'data\customui\python.png'
        y: self.parent.y + 10
        x: - self.parent.width/2 + 25
        width: self.parent.width - 20
        height: self.parent.height - 20

    Label:
        size_hint:(0.9, 1)
        text: "hello there"
        y: self.parent.y
        x: self.parent.x + self.parent.width*0.05
        width: self.parent.width
        height: self.parent.height
        text_size: self.size
        font_size: self.height - 30
        halign: 'left'
        valign: 'middle'

    Label:
        size_hint:(0.9, 1)
        text: "no u"
        y: self.parent.y
        x: self.parent.x + self.parent.width*0.7
        width: self.parent.width
        height: self.parent.height
        text_size: self.size
        font_size: self.height - 30
        halign: 'left'
        valign: 'middle'

    Label:
        size_hint:(0.9, 1)
        text: "dong big dumb"
        y: self.parent.y
        x: self.parent.x + self.parent.width*0.8
        width: self.parent.width
        height: self.parent.height
        text_size: self.size
        font_size: self.height - 30
        halign: 'left'
        valign: 'middle'
...

<Client>:
    ...
            ScrollView:
                GridLayout:
                    id:list_files
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    row_default_height:50
                    cols:1
```

### Snippets - main.py

```
class FileTemplate(Button):
    pass


class Client(Screen):
    ...
    def auto(self, dt):

        projects = self.sftp.listdir('.')

        for file in projects:

            if file[0] == ".":
                projects.remove(file)

        list_view = self.ids.list_files

        print(projects)

        for file in projects:
            list_view.add_widget(FileTemplate())
```